# Does this Python elasticsearch SSL error mean transport integrity is compromised: "When using `ssl_context` all other SSL related kwargs are ignored"?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, ssl

I have configured an SSL connection to my Elastic Cloud cluster thus:

```
# SSL client authentication using client_cert and client_key - as per https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

context = create_default_context (cafile=<path to .pem file>)

# connect to the Elasticsearch container

es =\
    Elasticsearch([<path to elasticsearch host>],\
                  http_auth=(<user>, <pword>), scheme="https", ssl_context=context)
print("Connected to the Elasticsearch server")
```

When I run the script I don't get an error, but I do get this warning:

`` UserWarning: When using `ssl_context`, all other SSL related kwargs are ignored ``

I've done some research which seems to indicate that this warning can be ignored. Specifically, https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1115 suggests that "The warning is wrong, because we are only setting the ssl_context parameter and nothing else."

I'm very new to integrating SSL into Python scripting / elasticsearch. My question is basically - does my connection look ok, can this warning be ignored?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the output of es.ping() ?

Comment: @Lupanoide - "True"

Comment: So you can ping your es server with that ssl configuration. You are able to query against it with es object

Comment: @Lupanoide - yes, that's correct, I can writer to the es cluster. But is that transport configuration correct and secure, ie is it encrypted correctly? Thanks!